# iTunes Connect not showing the build after resubmission of app

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I have searched for the solutions but none worked for me. I have uploaded the build so many times, it also shows processing in the activity tab but after finishing upload from Xcode, it just vanished. On clicking the Add button under the Build Option on iTunes Connect, it shows me the old build, the rejected one.

I also have the `NSCameraUsageDescription` and `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` strings in **Info.plist**.

What could be the problem? Any help?

Comment: may be binary is rejected due to some reasons , check your email which is associated with developer account for rejection reason.

Comment: thanks @NaumanMalik i have checked it and it is asking me to add microphone permission. Thanks for your response

Comment: glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you see your build under **My Apps/TestFlight/Builds/iOS** with a Missing Compilance warning, you should click on the yellow triangle and on **Provide Export Compliance Information** afterwards.

[image: Provide Export Compliance Information popup]

After you provided the necessary information, your version will be selectable.

Comment: i have checked but there is no option like missing compliance warning.